# Isometry in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that must be written as the product of 3 reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Essentially the question is:

> Find an isometry in $\mathbb{C}$ (=$\mathbb{R}^2$) that requires three
>   reflections. That is to say, cannot be written as the product of one
>   or two reflections.

We have just shown that any isometry in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as the product of at most n+1 reflections.

I feel like this should be one of the easier questions I'm doing but for whatever reason I just don't see any way to go about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a [glide reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_reflection) is the combination of a reflection (in a line) and a translation (along that same line). Have you seen any other relationship between a translation and reflections?